# UIAlertController (UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet) with iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, uialertcontroller

In iOS 8 to get *add photo* alert functionality, I do:

```
UIAlertController * view=   [UIAlertController
                             alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                             message:nil
                             preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* choosePhoto = [UIAlertAction
                     actionWithTitle:@"Choose Exisiting"
                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                     handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                     {
                         [self selectPhoto];

                     }];
[view addAction:choosePhoto];
...
```

How can I do the same thing in iOS7?

`UIAlertController` does not work with iOS7.1 and `UIAlertView` does not provide such functionality.

Comment: I think you're looking for `UIActionSheet`

Comment: Could you add solution ?

Comment: @DaRk-_-D0G...just did

Answer (score 2):

As requested above, I answer my own question:

```
- (void)updateWithActionSheet:(BOOL)isNew
{
    NSString *destructiveButtonTitle  = nil;
    if (!isNew) {
        destructiveButtonTitle = @"Delete it";
    }

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                                                             delegate:self
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                               destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle
                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"Choose Exisiting", @"Take Photo", nil];


    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSString *buttonTitle = [actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]) {
        [self.firstNameTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Choose Exisiting"]) {
        [self selectPhoto];
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Take Photo"]) {
        [self takePhoto];
    }
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Delete it"]) {
        [self deletePhoto];
    }
}
```